# Create control panel for drupal 7 site

Tags: 7

When i use drupal 6, i install [control panel](http://drupal.org/project/controlpanel) module and change panels  and authenticated users can goes to control_panel page and manage contents,pages and site.
but this module is not available for drupal 7.

my question is  how do you create a management page for your site in drupal 7 ?

Do you use another module or  add some php code to page and create this page manually?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: You could create a taxonomy (vocabulary) for your administrative features and use that with Taxonomy Menu. Add an image field to your terms with icon.  Or, just use Views to create your custom menu -- you'll be able to use your taxonomy term images there.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can set an administration theme. By default this is set to Seven, one of the core themes, but you can make it anything you want. Looking at the Control Panel module, it strikes me as very similar to the Root Candy theme. Give that a shot.
1. Download and install Root Candy
2. On the Appearance admin page scroll to the bottom and set Root Candy as your admin theme.

Or if Root Candy doesn't fit your needs, create a custom theme and use that for your admin theme.

There is also the new dashboard module that users with appropriate permissions can add links to pages they frequently use. The dashboard is then displayed at the top of the screen much like the admin menu.

Answer (score 0):

The module you've provided an example actually has a [7 version in he git repo](http://drupalcode.org/project/controlpanel.git/tree/refs/heads/7.x-1.x). Although, there isn't really any idea how it currently works.

Although from the screenshot, one could set an administration theme and simply include a menu block on a particular upon login.

**Administrative modules**

I've also provided a list of administrative modules. Here are some tools that significantly improve administrative user experience:

- [Contextual admin](http://drupal.org/project/context_admin) provides you lots of abilities to create rich
  user interfaces for administrating a Drupal website. The maintainer
  also provides lots of helpful videos and tutorials. He recently did a
  very good demonstration of this for in [drupalcamp austin](http://2011.drupalcampaustin.org/sessions/customizable-administration-tools)
- [Admin menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) creates a dropdown toolbar to allow administrators
  ease and access to many different parts of the administrative site.
- [Toolbar](http://drupal.org/project/toolbar),can also provide a great user menu for non-developers. Often admin_menu is very intimidating and has superfluous links thus i often set roles and assign a toolbar to a particular role. This allows you to create links centered on a role.